# calling restful web api from lua asynchronously

Tags: web-services, lua

I'm only concerned with Windows here but I'm trying to find a lua library that allows me to consume restful web api's asynchronously (a callback function that's called when the response comes back). I'm looking for a sort of angular/jquery style of web api calls in Lua. Why lua? The game engine I use supports lua so that's why I'm looking for this but it's proving to be rather complex in finding something.

I mean I can find something like https://github.com/lusis/lua-httpclient but it seems synchronous which won't work since the game loop needs to not be stalled waiting for a response. Most libraries I've found seem to be synchronous so just reaching out to anyone who has experience in this area.

Comment: This isn't much help, but [Corona SDK's implementation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/network/index.html) is async and uses a callback interface. Also, [lua-http](https://github.com/daurnimator/lua-http) claims to be async, but I've never used that one.

Comment: Hello, asking for a software or library recommendation is not what SO is about. Please describe the problem, what you have tried so far, and maybe someone can help you with a solution.